# Error trying to use Spatial data with Entity Framework

Tags: serialization, entity-framework-5, geospatial, spatial-query

I've got a SQL database that contains some spatial data. I also have an application that uses entity framework to generate the ORM mapping for this database. Every time I try to run the application I get the following error

> "System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry cannot be serialized because it does
>   not have a parameterless constructor."

I understand why the error is happening, but what I don't know is how to fix it. All the code in my *.edmx* file is generated by visual studio. What do I need to do to be able to serialize the data in my geometry column?